# data won't retrieve from local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

i have created a simple todo list site and i wanted to store data in local storage with 0 experience in JavaScript but some how i managed to store the data under key (todos) and now im stuck on how to retrieve data i searched a lot of articles and tried all solutions but non worked like getitem and document.write here is my code please help

```
let todoItems = [];


function addTodo(text) {
    const todo = {
        text,
        checked: false,
        id: Date.now()
    };
    todoItems.push(todo);
    console.log(todoItems);
    renderTodo(todo);
    
}

            <div class="todos-list__li-text">
                <div class = "todos-list__li-text-1"> ${todo.text}</div>
                <svg class="todos-list__li-text-2" width="170" height="4" viewBox="0 0 194 4" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path id="line" d="M0 2L194 2" stroke="url(#paint0_linear)" stroke-width="3.2"/>
                        <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="194" y1="2.00012" x2="0" y2="2.00003" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <stop stop-color="#7DCEE8"/>
                    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#30BDEA"/>
                    </linearGradient>
                    </defs>
                </svg>
            </div> 
            
            <button class="todos-list__li-delete-todo "><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>  </button>
            </label>
        `;
    console.log(node);
    list.append(node);
    window.localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todoItems));
}
```

where exactly should i put the retrieve  code ?

[photo of the local storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a78UT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve your list back with: localStorage.getItem('todos')

Comment: i tried that but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

you retrieve items by `localStorage.getItem`, but localStorage only store strings, so in order to get the iterable of your store item, you can:

```js
const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
```

Comment: i tried that but didn't work ):

Comment: @سعود provide the code block where you tried so we can help

Comment: my pleasure (https://pastebin.com/HTVpBBmg)

Answer (score -1):

try using this `window.localStorage.getItem("todos");`

i would suggest that you check in the first place under(in google chrome dev tool) application -> localstorage if your value is stored or not